# Finding the missing digits of $23!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, number-systems, decimal-expansion

It is given $23!=2585201xy38884976640000$. Now it is required to find the value of $x$ and $y$. I know I could find it by using divisibility rules and solving simultaneous equations. Is there any other way to solve it (without computing it by a calculator)? This question is just out of curiosity.

Comment: _Another way to solve it_ would be just to compute the factorial ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm-This though came into my mind when I saw it at first but the method is not useful if it given to you when you do not posses a calculator (maybe during an exam).

Comment: I don't have a calculator, but I do have a computer... `perl -e 'system join "*","calc 1",2..23'`

Comment: @HenningMakholm-What about during an exam?:-)

Comment: Why wouldn't you use divisibility rules? Henry's shortcut is great, but even if that doesn't occur to you, the rules for 9 and 11 leave you with $\left\{\begin{aligned}x+y&=4\text{ or }13\\x-y&=-1\end{aligned}\right.$ which is quick to solve.

Answer (score 14):

Hint: $23!$ is a multiple of $99$

Comment: How do you want to continue?

Comment: This is a great hint. +$1$.

Comment: @tatan: It's easy to compute residues modulo 99 if you go to base 100...

Answer (score 3):

Given $23!=2585201xy38884976640000$, Now Here $23!$ must Contain a no. $3,9$

So $\bf{R.H.S}$ must be divisible by  $3$ and $9$

If no. is Divisible by $3\;,$ Then Sum of Digit on $\bf{R.H.S}$ is divisible by $3$

So $2+5+8+5+2+0+1+x+y+3+8+8+8+4+9+7+6+6+4$ must be divisible by $3$

So $88+x+y$ is divisible by $3$

So $1+x+y$ must be divisible by $3$

So $x+y = 2,5,8,11,14,17$

Similarly  If no. is Divisible by $9\;,$ Then Sum of Digit on $\bf{R.H.S}$ is divisible by $9$

So $2+5+8+5+2+0+1+x+y+3+8+8+8+4+9+7+6+6+4$ must be divisible by $9$

So $88+x+y$ is divisible by $9$

So $7+x+y$ must be divisible by $9$

So $x+y = 2,11$

Now also Divisibility test for $11$. If no. is divisibility by $11$

Then $\displaystyle \bf{(Sum \; of odd\; position \; no)-(sum\; of \; evev \; position\; no.)}$ must be divisible by $11$

So $(48+y)-(38+x) = 10-(y-x)$ is divisible by $11$

Comment: I can solve it by using divisibility rules.But as I mentioned in the question,I am looking for a different method.

Comment: If you were using divisibility rules, I'd also use the one for $11$ and the one for $9$.

Comment: considering $3$ is of couse redundant if you consider $9$ anyway ...